# What are potential side effects of myostatin inhibitors?

Tags: physiology, pharmacology, muscles

Myostatin inhibitors, which are being developed to treat muscle wasting diseases like muscular dystrophy, are likely to be abused by athletes. What are the potential long-term side-effects of taking a myostatin inhibitor? Will it have different side-effects for patients compared to healthy athletes (especially young athletes that are still developing)?  Could there be adverse drug interactions with other common performance enhancing drugs like EPO, hGH, and anabolic steroids?

Sources I've explored (StackExchange is only allowing me to insert two hyperlinks):

- *New Muscle Drugs Could Be The Next Big Thing In Sports Doping* - NPR story by Jon Hamilton
- Wikipedia entry on myostatin
- Wyeth found one of its drugs to be safe in a clinical trial, but it stopped development because the drug was ineffective at increasing muscle mass.
- An internet search mainly brings up dieting and body building forums, which I do not trust.
- According to a review by [Breitbart et al. 2011](http://ajpheart.physiology.org/content/300/6/H1973), myostatin inhibition does not have negative effects on cardiac tissue.
- According to a review by [Allen et al. 2012](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3192366/), the increase in muscle mass caused by myostatin inhibition leads to be metabolic health (e.g. lower glucose levels and higher insulin sensitivity).